# PHP/HTML issue placing div content next to each other

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a small issue. I am trying to create a Treeview of a number of categories pulled out of the database. These categories should be placed next to each other (with a little space between them). Have been trying quite some css styling etc, but always get those categories underneath each other, no matter what I try it seems. Also cleared my cache several times without success. Does anyone have an idea on how to get this done ? It is dynamically, so it can be that there are 2, 3 or more categories to be displayed next to one other. Those categories should have a Treeview of corresponding subcategories and documents which is not yet coded.

My relevant code so far :

```
<div class="d-flex two-column-wrapper" id="twocols-wrapper">

<main class="instruments-wrapper">
<div class="card bg-light col-md-6 offset-md-3">
  <div class="card-header row align-items-center">
    <h3 class="text-center"><?=$this->instrument->name?></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content">
    <?php foreach ($this->categories as $category):?>
      <div class="category">
            <li class='active'><?=$category->name?></li>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach;?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

And in CSS :

```
content{
  width: auto;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: visible;
}

.category{
   width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `display: inline-block;` CSS property on the `<li>` element. Like so...

```
<div class="d-flex two-column-wrapper" id="twocols-wrapper">

<main class="instruments-wrapper">
<div class="card bg-light col-md-6 offset-md-3">
  <div class="card-header row align-items-center">
    <h3 class="text-center">Drum</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="category">
            <li class='active'>Snare</li>
            <li class='active'>High-hat</li>
            <li class='active'>Base</li>
            <li class='active'>Cymbal</li>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.category li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em; 
}
```

Working version here: https://jsfiddle.net/fraggley/wrox5198/7/

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! Tried it, but no luck. Also, when I open your working version, they also appear underneath each other ... . Can it be because of my browser (Safari) ?

Comment: What about using good old tables ? I guess I can solve it with <td></td> but I have read in the past better not to use tables, but can't remember why .. .

Comment: The screenshot you sent is the way it should be yes, but when I try your suggestions and open your link, they appear underneath each other .. .

Comment: Just tried your link on a Windows PC with Chrome. The items "Snare", "Base" etc also appear underneath each other, so seems nothing to do with my browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap 4, you can use [d-display-block](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/display/#notation) class:

```css
content{
  width: auto;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: visible;
}

.category{
   width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex two-column-wrapper" id="twocols-wrapper">

<main class="instruments-wrapper">
<div class="card bg-light col-md-6 offset-md-3">
  <div class="card-header row align-items-center">
    <h3 class="text-center"><?=$this->instrument->name?></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="category">
            <li class='active d-inline-block'>AAA</li>
            <li class='active d-inline-block'>BBBB</li>
            <li class='active d-inline-block'>CCCC</li>
            <li class='active d-inline-block'>DDDD</li>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using bootstrap 4 indeed. Tried your suggestions, but they are still underneath ech other .. .Tried to empty my cache, but still the same. Can it be because of my browser ? (am on Mac, Safari)